# Get highchart chart absolute coordinates

Tags: highcharts

I want to display some toolip on hover in chart. Is there a way to get absolute coordinates of mouse when hover inside chart. I can find plotX and plotY but they are not giving absolute positions.

Comment: You mean the real position of your the mouse in all the html page ?

Comment: Do you mean get coordinates related to chart or global document/window?

Comment: Try that http://jsfiddle.net/5KHaj/5/